# Hyperlink click event not working with phonegap but works on browser

Tags: javascript, cordova, knockout.js

Below is part of my code which is working fine if run on browser but function "incrementClickCounter" is not being triggered if used with phonegap and run on device

```
    <div class="newsheading">
    <h1><a id="newsTitle" data-bind="text:title,click:function () { 
    incrementClickCounter(title, content, publish_date, $index());}"></a></h1>
    </div>

    function incrementClickCounter(title=null, content=null, date=null, index=null){
    alert('hello');
    }
```

I tried calling button click event as well. but no luck.
Am i missing anything like js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should be situated in `<head>`, like this:

```
<head>
<script>
function incrementClickCounter(){
    alert('hello');
    }
</script>
</head>
```

And, by the way, what are attributes for? You are not accessing them, so remove them.

Comment: I put it in <head> tags but still not working. It works when run on browser

Comment: Then remove useless function attributes